# How to split pandas dataframe based on difference of values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, split, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a few columns, one called 'strike.' If the value of a row of the strike column is greater than 100 plus the previous row of the strike column, I want to split the dataframe into two at that point (they'd still have the same column names) and so on. I'm quite new at pandas and couldn't figure out a simple way to do this after looking up some functions.

An example: The following dataframe:

```
strike crv vol
1400   w   a 
1450   x   b
1600   y   c
1800   z   d
```

would come out to be 3 dataframes:

```
strike crv vol
1400   w   a 
1450   x   b

strike crv vol
1600   y   c

strike crv vol
1800   z   d
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mean something like `df[(df['strike'] > 100) & (df['strike'].shift() > 100)].index[0]`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IIUC, this is yet another example of the compare-cumsum-groupby pattern:

```
>>> df
   strike crv vol
0    1400   w   a
1    1450   x   b
2    1600   y   c
3    1800   z   d
>>> group_ids = (df["strike"] > (df["strike"].shift() + 100)).cumsum()
>>> grouped = df.groupby(group_ids)
>>> for k,g in grouped:
...     print("-----")
...     print(g)
...     
-----
   strike crv vol
0    1400   w   a
1    1450   x   b
-----
   strike crv vol
2    1600   y   c
-----
   strike crv vol
3    1800   z   d
```

And you can put this into a list or dictionary if you'd like:

```
>>> group_list = [g for k,g in grouped]
>>> group_list[2]
   strike crv vol
3    1800   z   d
>>> group_dict = dict(list(grouped))
>>> group_dict[1]
   strike crv vol
2    1600   y   c
```

---

This works because we build the group ids taking advantage of the fact that True == 1 and False == 0:

```
>>> df["strike"] > (df["strike"].shift() + 100)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: strike, dtype: bool
>>> (df["strike"] > (df["strike"].shift() + 100)).cumsum()
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
Name: strike, dtype: int64
```

and we can then group on these values.

Comment: Awesome, just what l was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @user3078608: I wouldn't ordinarily mention it, but it doesn't look like you've ever accepted an answer.  Are you familiar with the process?

Comment: @user3078608: no worries.  It looks like there are a few other people who have helped you in previous questions who could use some accepts too (always nice to get a late accept!)