# How to split pandas dataframe based on time gaps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with a column "DATE_TIME".

| DATE_TIME | SAMPLE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-10 10:52:48 | 1 | 3.22 |
| 2020-12-10 10:52:54 | 2 | 2.93 |
| 2020-12-10 10:53:00 | 3 | 2.27 |

I want to split the data frame into different data frames whenever the time gap is bigger than 5 minutes.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543697/how-to-split-pandas-dataframe-based-on-difference-of-values-in-a-column) very useful, but is not solving my problem as it is not creating data frames. I cannot find the mistake:

```
all_data["DATE_TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(all_data["DATE_TIME"])

group_samples = (all_data["DATE_TIME"].dt.minute > (all_data["DATE_TIME"].dt.minute.shift() + 5)).cumsum()
grouped = all_data["DATE_TIME"].dt.minute.groupby(group_samples)
group_list = [g for k,g in grouped]
group_list[2]

Out[]
1097    53
1100    53
1103    53
1106    54
1109    54
1112    54
1115    54
1118    54
1121    54
1124    54
1127    55
1130    55
...
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: `grouped = all_data["DATE_TIME"].dt.minute.groupby(group_samples)` should just be `grouped = all_data.groupby(group_samples)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grouped = all_data["DATE_TIME"].dt.minute.groupby(group_samples)` should just be `grouped = all_data.groupby(group_samples)`

The problem with the first is you're only grouping a series that has just the minutes. So the output will only have the minutes of the split dataframe.

Changing that to grouping the full dataframe by the `group_samples` gives you all the columns in the output.